# FLEX ReferenceError in SystemManager at startup?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, referenceerror

So I am having a strange error this morning.  My Adobe FLEX app was compiling just fine on Friday, but now today whenever I attempt to debug or run it, I am getting this runtime error right at the very beginning:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::topMostIndex not found on _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value.
at mx.managers::SystemChildrenList/addChild()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemChildrenList.as:128]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2014]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2582]
```

That is the only trace that comes out with it, so it looks to me like it's something built into FLEX and not my code that may be hiccuping.  I've had strange errors before that a Clean was able to solve, but I have attempted to clean and rebuild my debug version but I am still getting this error.  I restarted Flash Builder, and even restarted my computer - no dice.  Even when I export a release build, my firefox flash debugger catches the same error.  Existing copies on my app on the web seem unaffected.  I reinstalled my flash content debugger for netscape (I use firefox as my main browser) and no go.  I don't even think an update was automatically installed for flash as I have it notify me rather than just do it (even double checked those settings).

Short of just reinstalling flash or flash builder I am not sure what to do.  Any suggestions?  I am at a loss for what this error means or how to fix it.  I am not even ruling out the possibility that I messed something up in my code, but I have no idea where to look as the stack trace only has 3 lines - and none of which is my code.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:  I want to add, if I dismiss the error, the application continues running seemingly normally.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? Have you tried compiling with another version?

Comment: I have 4.6.0.  I have not tried a different version - how would I go about trying a different version of the SDK?  AFAIK this is the version that came with my FlashBuilder 4.6 and the version I have always used.

Comment: Can you run in debug mode?  If so; it should give you the full stack trace.  Theoretically there is something deepre in the stack trace causing the issue.

Comment: The stack trace above is all that the FlashBuilder Debugger is showing me.  Let me see if I can find a way to get more information...

Comment: This sounds like some sort of version mismatch between Flex SDK's. A library you use may have been compiled w/an earlier version of Flex... or something like that. The property the error complains about (`topMostIndex`) does exist on the `SystemManager` class in the mx_internal namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with you these days. With firefox flash player plugin.The difference is that I used modules. If I ignore the error, the project doesn't work.

But I found that there is no error with ie or opera.

Now I am using opera.

---

I tried these ways:

- clean project
- create a new project
- create a new workspace and a new project
- reinstall flash builder
- install the latest flash player plugin

All of these didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same error by last week.
After few research it's like the bug is due to flashFirebug extension in Firefox.
Try disable the plugin, restart your Firefox and try again.
This solve the problem for me.
Hope that help...

[source](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4857769)